# Overriding ES6 class behaviour with traps

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have recently learned about `Proxy` objects in javascript, and how you can use a Proxy object to hook into `Object.defineProperty` for custom behaviour (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664861/3808312) if I'm being too vague).

I would like to do the same, but to an entire class so that I can achieve something similar to C#'s `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Essentially, the class will be an `EventEmitter` that emits data when a property is changed.

```
class SyncedObject extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.ValueA = 1;
        this.ValueB = 2;
    }

    // Emit this when a property is changed
    emitPropertyChanged( eventArgs ) {
        // eventArgs.propertyName
        // eventArgs.oldValue
        // eventArgs.newValue

        this.emit( 'propertyChanged', eventArgs );
    }
}
```

Is this something I can do in an ES6 class? I understand `Proxy` has a `get()` and `set()` traps that could achieve this kind of thing, but I'm not sure how to go about writing a class that is automatically wrapped in a `Proxy`.

Comment: It's ES6. And there's no ES7. Yes, this can be achieved with Proxy. Depending on your case, it may be better to use get/set accessors for performance reasons; Proxy is considerably slower.

Comment: Fixed the title. Getters and setters would work, but my particular use case would benefit from being able to dynamically hook into an arbitrary object's properties. I don't expect the properties to update more than once every minute, so in this case performance isn't a huge issue

Comment: on the entire class, in what sense ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to somehow apply the `Proxy` traps to the entire `SyncedObject` class. I have also been pondering the idea of turning `SyncedObject` into a `Proxy` itself and then using it to "wrap" other objects, but the only way I can think of implementing that is by having a property that holds the object in question, so I'd have to do something like `SyncedObject.Data.ValueA`, which I want to avoid if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering, I've been able to more or less achieve what I was hoping to

```
const EventEmitter = require( 'events' );

class SyncedObject extends EventEmitter { 
  constructor( obj ) {
    super();
    this._object = obj;

    return new Proxy( this, {
      set: ( object, key, value, proxy ) => {
        if( this._object[key] === value )
          return false;

        this._object[key] = value;
        if( key[0] === '_') {
            var eventArgs = {
              propertyName: key,
              oldValue: object[key],
              newValue: value
            };
            this.emit( 'propertyChanged', eventArgs );
        }

        return true;
      },
      get: ( object, key ) => {
        return this._object[key] || object[key];
      }
    });
  }

  silentUpdate( data ) {
    for(var i = 0, keys = Object.keys(data); i < keys.length; i++)
      this._object[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
  }

}
```

Not the most bulletproof solution (EventEmitter properties raise the event), but for what I need, it will likely do. If anyone has improvement suggestions, please do post. I'll leave this question open for the time being.